# SP13 - How to get source ListItem from variation ListItem with C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, development, splistitem, variations

I have a case where need to get source ListItem by variation ListItem with C#?

How to do this?

```
var variationList = myWeb.Lists["variationListName"];

var variationListItems = variationList.Items;

foreach(ListItem variationItem in variationListItems)
{
  ...how to get source item by target?

}
```

Comment: Sorry, what does "source" mean in this case?

Comment: SPListItem where i sync in another web

Comment: A custom column?

Comment: Are you using CSOM or SSOM?